# Drawn Grid Offset

Tags: java, android, ondraw

I am trying to draw a grid for a game but my lines are offset from where I want them. I have tried adding a fixed offset but I want it to be scaleable on difference devices.

Here is the code for creating the path the View will draw:

```
    float top = getPaddingTop() + getTop();
    float bot = getBottom() - getPaddingBottom();
    float left = getLeft() + getPaddingLeft();
    float right = getRight() - getPaddingRight();
    float squareWidth = (right - left) / 10;
    float squareHeight = (bot - top) / 10;

    gridPath.moveTo(left, top);
    gridPath.lineTo(left, bot);
    gridPath.lineTo(right, bot);
    gridPath.lineTo(right, top);

    gridPath.close();

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        gridPath.moveTo(squareWidth * i, top);
        gridPath.lineTo(squareWidth * i, bot);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        gridPath.moveTo(left, squareHeight * i);
        gridPath.lineTo(right, squareHeight * i);
    }

    gridPath.close();
```

I want an evenly drawn grid but I get this:[image]

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accounting for the left and top paddings in your `for` loops:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    gridPath.moveTo(getPaddingLeft() + squareWidth * i, top);
    gridPath.lineTo(getPaddingLeft + squareWidth * i, bot);
}

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    gridPath.moveTo(left, getPaddingTop() + squareHeight * i);
    gridPath.lineTo(right, getPaddingTop() + squareHeight * i);
}
```

Also, the `getLeft()`, `getRight()`, `getTop()`, `getBottom()` methods are relative to the `View`'s position in its parent, so your initializations are going to cause problems if the `View` doesn't happen to fill its parent. The following is probably preferable:

```
float top = getPaddingTop();
float bot = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom();
float left = getPaddingLeft();
float right = getWidth() - getPaddingRight();
```

Comment: But I am when I calculate squareWidth I need to do it again?

Comment: Yes, because that's just to do with the square's width, not its x-coordinate offset.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought I had it taken care of but it needs to be added again because of what you said. Thank you!

Comment: @JBlaz I shoulda mentioned earlier, but you might consider using `Canvas#drawLine()` methods instead using of a `Path` for your grid. It's generally faster.

Comment: Okay thank you! Do you mean it is faster like it draws to the screen faster and makes the app more responsive?

Comment: Yeah, it draws faster. You might have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15208783) from Romain Guy, an engineer at Google, for a little explanation.