# Fast paths drawing

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint

I make a paint app that use array of finger paths for drawing them on screen.
now by paths array increasing, app work and draw slower than past.
What ways you recommend for its faster drawing?

Comment: [Drawing paths and hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039829/drawing-paths-and-hardware-acceleration)

Comment: @RonTLV  with this way : save to a bitmap, undo_redo  in my paint app is limited and reduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rephrase.  Currently, you're doing a software draw finger painting app, which sounds like its using vector graphics.

Learn OpenGL and use hardware acceleration to draw.

Alternatively, you could create a back buffer and render to that, then do a quick copy.

Comment: A shorter way recomend please!

Comment: My app is offline, by this state i use back buffer?